# Editing multiple files simultaneously with Vim

Tags: vim, vi

I need to add several lines all at the same location to multiple files. I was wondering if I could possibly open all files with Vim, and only make the changes in one file for which the changes will be made in all files simultaneously. I really want to avoid opening X number of files, copying this, pasting, then repeating for each file of X files...There's gotta be a better way to do this, hopefully with vim...

Thanks!
Amit

Comment: Why vim? If you have identical files (or with the exact same structure) you can script it easily in almost any language.

Comment: Oh WOW that is so freaking true. Why didn't I think of it. !@$@#$@#$#@$

Comment: If you're super comfortable with vim and not other scripting languages, see vim's man page for the `-w` and `-s` options -- they let you record a session as a script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could record macro and execute it on other files. See http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/01/vi-and-vim-macro-tutorial-how-to-record-and-play/ for detailed tutorial.

Comment: I checked out the tutorial, I found it very helpful, though I think I'll just quickly throw something into python to do this all for me...It'll probably be SO much easier...Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `windo` command to operate in all windows. Combine this with a `substitute` command and you have this (say you want to add "`This is a new line.`" at line 2 in every file):

```
:windo 2s/\(.*\)/This is a new line.^M\1
```

Off course, as others noted, there are much better tools for this job (awk comes to mind).

Comment: Thank you for that. What is this `awk` that you speak of, or do you just mean awkward...

Comment: @Amit: I mean `awk`, the [scripting language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awk#Sample_applications)