# How can I edit multiple files simultaneously with sublime?

Tags: sublimetext

I have many similar files where I want to be able to edit them all at once. Like with multiple cursors on one file but with single cursors on a couple of files. How can I do this?

Comment: This is not possible. Only 1 view (open file) can be edited at a time.

Comment: Seems like a task best suited to your favourite scripting language. If you don't have any scripting language in your toolbox it is a vital tool to add. See this conversation for a related discussion [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084919/editing-multiple-files-simultaneously-with-vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084919/editing-multiple-files-simultaneously-with-vim)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `ctrl + shift + f` to bring up the `find in files` panel and simultaneously update files that contain the same `find` search term, however it is a blind search/replace function.

Answer (score 0):

A better option would be to use a utility tool like TextCrawler which allows searching in multiple files and replaces them accordingly. It offers a variety of settings to meet almost all your needs in the document and file editing arena https://www.digitalvolcano.co.uk/tcdownloads.html  [[image: view a sample screenshot of the tool]][1image]

Answer (score 0):

I realize this answer does not use the tool sublime-text that you mentioned. But allow me to suggest another good way (using open source tools).

Using the Hyper console along with hyper-broadcast plugin (https://hyper.is/store/hyper-broadcast) [The link says "store" but this is all FOSS]

You can open multiple windows in your console (DOS/bash) then using a text-based editor and then send the same keystrokes simultaneously.

Answer (score -4):

Taken from the [Sublime webpage](https://www.sublimetext.com/):

> #### Split Editing
>
> Get the most out of your wide screen monitor with split editing support. Edit files side by side, or edit two locations in the one file. You can edit with as many rows and columns as you wish.
>
> Take advantage of multiple monitors by editing with multiple windows, and using multiple splits in each window.
>
> **Take a look at the *View/Layout* menu for split editing options. To open multiple views into the one file, use the *File/New View* into *File* menu item.**

Comment: Your answer says about different sublime features: 1. displaying multiple files side by side 2. editing one file with multiple cursors. The question is about editing multiple files simultaneously.